# ZF2 doctrine shared entity pool

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've setup a multi database connection on my ZF2 project with Doctrine, one to read from database and another to write.

Everything works good when used separately but when i try to use both on the same entity, like:

find a user:

$user = $this->**getReaderObjectManager**()->getRepository('Entity\User')->findOneBy(array('username' =>'xpto'));

and then try to change something:

$this->**getWriterObjectManager**()->persist($user);
$user->setBlabla('bla');

and then try to flush it:

$this->**getWriterObjectManager**()->flush();

nothin' happens. no good.

It seems that **readerObjectManager** and **writerObjectManager** have their independent "entity pool", so i cant persist and change one entity from the other manager.

Is there a way to pass an entity from one manager to the other, or reference it, or simple that both managers share the same "entity pool"?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have managed entities across multiple entity managers: that's unsupported and can lead to unexpected behavior.

If you really need to separate reads from writes, do so at connection level using a master/slave connection or by implementing your own `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` object.

Also, reads are usually not handled via an `ObjectManager`, but by an `ObjectRepository` (where you can implement custom in-memory strategy to optimize read operations).

Another way of handling this is to detach entities from the "read" `ObjectManager` and merging them back into the "write" `ObjectManager`.

Again, this is not suggested, and you should handle it at connection level or with a smarter implementation of a repository that fits your needs.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what do you mean "at connection level"?

Comment: This means that the connection object does decisions about what is handled with reads and what with writes (this usually happens with master/slave environments). If your problem is only related to PHP memory, use a very smart repository only.

Comment: The only problem is the necessity to read from one db and write in another (production environment settings). So, creating a custom DBALConnection it the way to go? Or is there a way that i can bypass the standard orm_default connection changing the connection information "on the fly" basead in the action of insert/update and select?

Comment: You can override the service `doctrine.connection.orm_default` and use doctrine's builtin MasterSlave connection: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connections/MasterSlaveConnection.php